# Statistics about php setups / What extensions are installed by default

Tags: php, mcrypt, phpinfo

I'm trying to get some statistics about how most PHP sites are configured, specifically what extensions are installed on them.

I'm particularly interested in knowing if Mcrypt is installed or not.

Anyone know of any sites collating such information?

Comment: any inputs folks? looking for an authroritative source  - a report of some kind... surely there  must be php websites doeing this?

Comment: I'm interested in this too, for the mb_string extension especially :)

Comment: Is the question : "what percentage of php instances from providers give you access to this extension ?" or "what percentage of php instaces have Mcrypt enabled ?". If the question if the first, you can have your answer quite easily, just do it by hosting provider / number of instances served, I'm pretty sure you can cover the top providers quickly. I can see sites collating the info about hosting providers - not about specific individual PHP instances (which are a minority anyway).

Answer (score 1):

Google does, by indexing phpinfo() -- so search for that using a string embedding in phpinfo.

like this: http://www.google.com/search?&q=%22If+you+did+not+receive+a+copy+of+the+PHP+license%2C+or+have+any+questions+about+PHP+licensing%2C+please+contact+license%40php.net%22

Comment: thanks @beans - i was looking for reports which either survery people or do scans.

Answer (score 1):

Interestingly, php site itself has a usage page, but seems like it was not updated after 2007 :(. The other lists are,

http://php.net/usage.php

http://w3techs.com/technologies/details/pl-php/all/all

http://trends.builtwith.com/framework/PHP

http://www.tiobe.com/index.php/paperinfo/tpci/PHP.html